# SSRS - Custom currency formatting with thousand and decimal separators

Tags: reporting-services

I have set currency formatting using the built-in formatting properties. Currency is currently shown like this in my report:

```
2208.64 €
```

I want it to be shown like **this**:

```
2.208,64 €
```

I changed textbox properties to use thousand separators and my custom format looks like this:

```
#,0.00 '€';#,0.00- '€'
```

However, I don't know how to change separators in custom formatting. Decimal separator needs to be a **comma** and thousand separator needs to be a **dot**.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the built-in formatting properties you can display your currency format like this:

[image]

If you change the language of the report (in the report properties under localization) you can control the dot or comma. For example:

```
DE = 12.000,00 
EN = 12,000.00
```

Comment: Forgot to look up my question, but yes this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!